# How to debug java in visual studio code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I was wondering if there is an easy straight forward way to run and debug java code in visual studio code.

Most of the tutorial I see out there require you to specify the project path or the class name you are debugging.  However, is it possible to just open the java file and just debug and have all the configuration automatically pick up.

Looking for simple open the file and click on debug and it starts the debugging without having to configure file for a specific java file.

I did look at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-debug but it looks like you have to specify the actual class you are debugging which is a pain.

[image]

If i try to use the launch vs code variable, it doesn't recognize it.  I'm not sure if this is a bug in the plugin or what.

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: Use something better like eclipse or intellij for Java :P

Comment: I use vs code for other language, so figure it'll be nice to be able to use this for java as well.  It's more light weight then eclipse or intellij.

Answer (score 0):

The debug configuration can be automatically generated by the VSCode. Normally, you doesn't need specify your main class or projectName. The extension will get these information from the project unless multiple main class or projects existing.

You can try the latest version of the vscode-java and debugger extension.